# MySQL - Finding users who requested a percentage change in another relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've got four tables (please see ERD below) and need a query which will search for the difference between the population for a city between 2019 and 2020 (using the YearData table) and if this is bigger than the percentage requested by the user (in the alert table) then the user's email address is shown. Hope this makes sense. Thanks for any help with this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a bunch of joins and some filtering logic:

```
select a.username
from alert a join
     yeardata yd2020
     on yd2020.lga = a.lga and yd2020.year = 2020 join
     yeardata yd2019
     on yd2019.lga = a.lga and yd2019.year = 2019
where yd2020.population >= yd2019.population * (1 + a.percent);
```

Comment: This directly solves the asked question, but there's a common potential problem of repeatedly re-calculating stats on historical numbers that will never change. If this code runs infrequently then it's not much of a concern, but if there are many users monitoring the same LGAs you're going to be re-calculating these same numbers repeatedly. I would suggest caching the year-on-year growth somewhere, probably in the `YearData` table itself.